# create widget class for stack in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, class, dart

i have a 5 stack in flutter and i want to ceate class for call in in ui .
i dont want to write many stack in ui.

i write this but not work .
can anyone know how can i do it ?
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.

..
.
.
.
.
.

this is part on my code in ui :

```
 Expanded(
            child: GridView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 25, right: 25),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                childAspectRatio: 2.5,
              ),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                 child: ImageCard("b.jpg","some",ListOfEpisode),
                ),
```

and this is class for it :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageCard extends StatefulWidget {
  ImageCard(String nameCard, String clickCard, Type imageName);

  get nameCard => null;
  get clickCard => null;
  get imageName => null;

  @override
  _ImageCardState createState() => _ImageCardState(imageName,nameCard,clickCard);
}

class _ImageCardState extends State<ImageCard> {
  _ImageCardState(imageName, nameCard, clickCard);

  String? get imageName => null;
  String? get nameCard => null;
  get clickCard => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/' + imageName!,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              " " + nameCard!,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      onTap: () {
        clickCard;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and i've get this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get nameCard => null;` means it will always return null, that's why you are getting the errors.

If you wish to check null value, make it nullable like  `final String? imageName;`

And while using this make sure it is not getting null value, simple way to promise by adding bang `!` at the end. But if you aren't sure, you can provide a default value like `imageName?? "defaultValue"`

**Widget**

```
class ImageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? imageName;
  final String? nameCard;
  final Function clickCard;

  const ImageCard({
    Key? key,
    this.imageName,
    this.nameCard,
    required this.clickCard,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/images/${imageName ?? "default image"}',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                " ${nameCard ?? "defaultCardname"}",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () {
        clickCard();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**UseCase**

```
GridView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 25, right: 25),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 15,
          mainAxisSpacing: 15,
          childAspectRatio: 2.5,
        ),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          ImageCard(
            clickCard: () {
              print("item pressed X ");
            },
            imageName: "name",
            nameCard: "cardname",
          ),
          ...List.generate(
            12,
            (index) => ImageCard(
              clickCard: () {
                print("item pressed $index ");
              },
              imageName: "name  $index",
              nameCard: "cardname $index",
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: when i've click on image . show a grey Rectangle background back it . how can i delete it ?

Comment: You can just replace `InkWell` with `GuesterDetector`,  or you can use `splashColor:Colors.transparent` on `inkWell`

Comment: i've try it in inkwel but not work and still i have it

Comment: Did you add `splashColor and hover property`, it will easy for you to use `GestureDetector`

Comment: i use this ->  InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Stack(....

Comment: i've set container for inkwel and its ok . i have one more question . when i've click on ontap and call class . can't call it . why ?

Comment: About that gray, set`highlightColor` and `splashColor` to transparent, you may also want to set hover color as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236385/discussion-between-yeasin-sheikh-and-siitaw).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning null from getters. That's why you are getting this error. I am not sure why do you need getters.
But this code will work

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class ImageCard extends StatefulWidget {
    String nameCard;
    String clickCard; 
    String imageName;

    ImageCard(this.nameCard, this.clickCard, this.imageName);
    
    @override

   _ImageCardState createState() => _ImageCardState(imageName,nameCard,clickCard);

}

class _ImageCardState extends State<ImageCard> {
    String nameCard;
    String clickCard; 
    String imageName;

    _ImageCardState(this.nameCard, this.clickCard, this.imageName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/' + imageName,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              " " + nameCard!,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      onTap: () {
        clickCard;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i've get this error : error:           The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Type'.)
error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.)

Comment: I have edited it. Mistakenly wrote Type instead of String